# Rejected bean name 'propertyConfigurer': no URL paths identified

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, servlets

I am playing with spring (btw I used to know spring when it uses configuration instead of annotation).

### pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>3.6.10.Final</hibernate.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
</properties>
```

### web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
      version="2.5">    

<display-name>Demo Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

### mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.service" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.hibernate" />

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

### jdbc.properties

```
jdbc.driverClassName= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:mysql://127.7.195.2:3306/tomcat2
jdbc.username=xxxx
jdbc.password=yyyy
```

### hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <mapping class="com.company.hibernate.Person" />
</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

### PersonServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {

@Autowired
private PersonDAO personDAO;

public void addPerson(Person person) {
    personDAO.addPerson(person);
}

public List<Person> listPerson() {
    return personDAO.listPerson();
}

public void removePerson(Integer id) {
    personDAO.removePerson(id);
}
}
```

### PersonDAOImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO {
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional
public void addPerson(Person person) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(person);
}
    @Transactional
public List<Person> listPerson() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Person").list();
}
    @Transactional
public void removePerson(Integer id) {
    Person person = (Person) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(Person.class, id);
    if (null != person) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(person);
    }
}
}
```

### PersonController.java

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {

private PersonService personService = new PersonServiceImpl();

@RequestMapping("/list")
public String listContacts(Map<String, Object> map) {

    map.put("person", new Person());
    map.put("personList", personService.listPerson());

    return "person";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addPerson(@ModelAttribute("person")
    Person person, BindingResult result) {

    personService.addPerson(person);

    return "redirect:/list";
}

@RequestMapping("/delete/{contactId}")
public String deleteContact(@PathVariable("personId")
Integer personId) {

    personService.removePerson(personId);

    return "redirect:/list";
}
}
```

### Person.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person {

@Id
@Column(name="ID")
private int id;

@Column(name="first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name="last_name")
private String lastName;

public Person() {
}

public Person(String fname, String lname) {
    this.firstName = fname;
    this.lastName = lname;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String first_name) {
    this.firstName = first_name;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String last_name) {
    this.lastName = last_name;
}
}
```

### Person.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="Person" table="PERSON">
  <meta attribute="class-description">
     This class contains the person detail. 
  </meta>
  <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
     <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
  <property name="firstName" column="first_name" type="string"/>
  <property name="lastName" column="last_name" type="string"/>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Somehow the Autowired doesn't work. Logging at tomcat log, there is no error. The only thing looks suspicious is the "Reject" lines:

```
Jan 31, 2014 5:52:26 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping detectHandlers
FINE: Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
Jan 31, 2014 5:52:26 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping detectHandlers
FINE: Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
...
Jan 31, 2014 5:52:27 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping detectHandlers
FINE: Rejected bean name 'personServiceImpl': no URL paths identified
Jan 31, 2014 5:52:27 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping detectHandlers
FINE: Rejected bean name 'personDAOImpl': no URL paths identified
Jan 31, 2014 5:52:27 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping detectHandlers
FINE: Rejected bean name 'propertyConfigurer': no URL paths identified
Jan 31, 2014 5:52:27 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping detectHandlers
FINE: Rejected bean name 'dataSource': no URL paths identified
Jan 31, 2014 5:52:27 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping detectHandlers
FINE: Rejected bean name 'sessionFactory': no URL paths identified
Jan 31, 2014 5:52:27 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping detectHandlers
FINE: Rejected bean name 'transactionManager': no URL paths identified
```

But when I access http://tomcat2-gyw97.rhcloud.com/myprj/list, the log spits out NPE:

```
FINE: Resolving exception from handler [com.company.controller.PersonController@1cfa07a]: java.lang.NullPointerException
Feb 01, 2014 10:57:09 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet processRequest
FINE: Could not complete request
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.company.service.PersonServiceImpl.listPerson(PersonServiceImpl.java:35)
        at com.company.controller.PersonController.listContacts(PersonController.java:27)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is in line 35 of `PersonServiceImpl`? Maybe a bean is not injected. Could you show us the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First problem

```
private PersonService personService = new PersonServiceImpl();
```

You are creating the object yourself instead of having Spring inject it for you. Spring can't autowire beans into objects it doesn't manage.

```
@Autowired
private PersonService personService;
```

Second problem, add this

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

to your `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`, otherwise Spring uses the default `DispatcherServlet` configuration which might not be what you want.

Also, this

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

serves no purpose at the moment since you don't have a `ContextLoaderListener`.

---

For the reject lines, ignore them. The `AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping` goes through all your beans to see if they could be used as request handlers.

Comment: Your suggestion resolved my current Autowired issue and now I am running into a hibernate issue. I will do more research on that. Thank  you for your help!!!

Comment: Now I am getting this error in tomcat when I hit the /list page: FINE: Resolving exception from handler [com.company.controller.PersonController@549381]: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here

Answer (score 3):

My Spring Boot application wasn't working, and I noticed the debug message `Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified`. Turns out that this wasn't a problem at all.. Spring is looking in registered beans for URL mappings - and it's no surprise it doesn't find mappings in many of beans.

So if your Spring web application isn't displaying a webpage, check your controller is annotated, a method has appropriate RequestMapping and class has been component scanned ok.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the other solution dint work since I dint autowire a service method and had the mvc annotation config in my servlet config. It is displayed you have set the logging level to "debug" and its for debugging purpose. To hide these from the logs just disable the DEBUG log for the `org.springframework` classes.